# how to get the sum of a column of other rows in the same group using dplyr or anything else?

Tags: r, dplyr

example data

```
set.seed(1)
d <- iris[sample.int(nrow(iris), 5), ]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
# 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica
# 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
```

for each row, I want to calculate a value, which is the sum of `Petal.Width` of the same `Species` in other rows. for example, for row 2, the only other row with the same species group is row 3, so the results will be sum(1.5).

expected output

```
d$newcol <- c(0.2, 1.5, 1.3, 0, 0.2)
# > d
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species newcol
# 40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa    0.2
# 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor    1.5
# 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor    1.3
# 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica    0.0
# 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa    0.2
```

I tried the following code, which didn't work:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(
        newcol = sum(Petal.Width[1:n() != row_number()])
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've grouped by `Species` you can take the `sum` of `Petal.Width` which all adds up all `Petal.Width` for that Species, and then subtract just a bare `Petal.Width` which subtracts the `Petal.Width` of the row.

Implementing this gives the following code which returns the expected output:

```
d %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = sum(Petal.Width) - Petal.Width
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R equivalent to the `dplyr` solution can be achieved with `ave`:

```
d$newcol <- ave(d$Petal.Width, d$Species, FUN=function(x) sum(x) - x)

d
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species newcol
40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa    0.2
56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor    1.5
85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor    1.3
134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica    0.0
30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa    0.2
```

`ave` is a typical grouping tool for creating new columns in a data.frame when performing group-level calculations.